# How often is the Windows7 phone marketplace being updated

Tags: windows-phone-7

How often is the Windows Market Place being updated? My app was certified and released, but I cannot find my app in the search even by the name of the app.

Comment: My App was immediately searchable. Did you try searching on non marketplace sites like wp7applist and markeplacebrowser ?

Comment: I don't see my app in any of the sites either. Here is my App URL (PetSounds) http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=eed9774a-7b46-4eeb-96ac-4e13fd44586d

Answer (score 2):

This may vary because your app has to be published to several servers for all locations / marketplaces.

Normally it should be searchable within a few hours (up to 24).